# Find all possible subsets of n elements (special powerset) . Ordering within a subset is not ignored.

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am unable to find the total number of possible subsets taking ordering into account.

For example:- take $2$ elements $1$ & $2$, then form subsets $(),(1),(2),(1,2),(2,1)$

Now here $(1,2)$ & $(2,1)$ are two different ordered sets and both should be counted.

Please help me find the total number of subsets for $n$ elements.

I have to program the above logic, so a formula derivation would help a lot.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_arrangements. The formula is $\lfloor en! \rfloor$.

Comment: I tweaked your formatting, which suffered from a lot of extra whitespace that threw off the [MarkDown formatting mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  For using proper mathematical notation, see [this introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).